Difference traceId between services with spring boot 3 -> spring boot 2
A different trace ID occurs when two services of different versions of Spring Boot interact. A very important note is that the sending side is spring boot 3, and the receiving side is spring boot 2. No notes help in solving the problem. Tried different settings with different variations.
Examples:
On side spring boot 3:
management:
tracing:
enabled: true
sampling:
probability: 1.0
propagation:
type: b3
On side spring boot 2:
spring:
sleuth:
trace-id128: true
supports-join: false
propagation:
type: b3, w3c
The trace match is observed only like this: 668bf86dfd1f566257411febfd3e6a37-> 668bf86d5a467c34d608bc9381400526

Providing the exact version numbers might help. Also, you need to make sure that they use the same propagation format (this might work out of the box by upgrading to Boot 3.2).
